# Swift class containing another class as var

Tags: ios, swift

Consider the following code:

```
class A {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    init(x vx: int, y vy: int){
        x = vx
        y = vy
    }
}

class B {
    var a_array: [A]

    init(){
        a_array = []
    }

    func append(_ a:A){
        a_array.append(a)
    }

    func sum_all(){
        var sum = 0
        for a in a_array {
            sum += (a.x + a.y)
        }
        print("sum all is",sum)
    }
}

var a1 = A(1, 2)
var a2 = A(3, 4)
var b = B();
b.append(a1)
b.append(a2)
b.sum_all() //it prints out 10 correctly.

a1.x = 2
b.sum_all() //it still prints out 10
```

As I want it prints out 11, how can I modify these code?
In C, it can be done by using a pointer reference easily, how can it be done in Swift?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please post the code you actually have tested with, this code doesn't even compile. Also when I fix the issues and execute the code it produces the expected output so I have no idea what so ever what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually printing 11 in the line you said it still prints 10.

You can try it out by modifying a bit your code to look more like Swift syntax as this:

```
import Foundation

class A {
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
    init(_ vx: Int, _ vy: Int){
        x = vx
        y = vy
    }
}

class B {
    var a_array: [A]

    init(){
        a_array = []
    }

    func append(_ a:A){
        a_array.append(a)
    }

    func sum_all(){
        var sum = 0
        for a in a_array {
            sum += (a.x + a.y)
        }
        print("sum all is",sum)
    }
}

var a1 = A(1, 2)
var a2 = A(3, 4)
var b = B()
b.append(a1)
b.append(a2)
print("first")
b.sum_all() //it prints out 10 correctly.

a1.x = 2
print("last")
b.sum_all() //it actually prints 11.
```

You can try the snippet by copy pasting it in this playground online http://online.swiftplayground.run/ and run it.

This is the output:

```
first
sum all is 10
last
sum all is 11
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I found it's correctly work. I just found in my real code, I defined A as a struct, this lead to a value reference. Thank you again!